# how to create a record for a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord, migration

I have the following associations set up:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :users_books
    has_many :users, through: :user_books
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users_books
    has_many :books, through: :users_books
end
```

I created a join table migration as I ought to

```
class CreateUsersBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
    def change
      create_table :users_books do |t|
        t.integer :user_id
        t.integer :book_id
      end
    end
  end
```

Now I need to create a method called check_out_book, that takes in a book and a due_date as arguments. When a user checks out a book, it should create a new UserBook record (or Checkout record or whatever you want to call you join table/model). That new UserBook record should have a attribute (and therefore table column) of returned? which should default to false. How would I go about creating this method and the migrations?

Comment: Is your `users_books` table a model as well or just a table?

Comment: Add `due_date` and `returned` columns to join table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tablenames and your associations in Rails should always be `singular_plural` with the exception of the odd duckling "headless" join tables used by the (pretty useless) `has_and_belongs_to_many` association.

```
class CreateUserBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  def change
    create_table :user_books do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :book
      t.boolean :returned, default: false
    end
  end
end
```

```
class UserBook < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
end
```

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :user_books
    has_many :users, through: :user_books
end
```

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_books
    has_many :books, through: :user_books
end
```

But you should really use a better more descriptive name that tells other programmers what this represents in the domain and not just a amalgamation of the two models it joins such as Loan or Checkout.

I would also use `t.datetime :returned_at` to create a datetime column that can record when the book is actually returned  instead of just a boolean.

If you want to create a join record with any additional data except the foreign keys you need to create it explicitly instead of implicitly (such as by `user.books.create()`).

```
@book_user = Book.find(params[:id]).book_users.create(user: user, returned: true)
# or
@book_user = current_user.book_users.create(book: user, returned: true)
# or
@book_user = BookUser.new(user: current_user, book: book, returned: true)
```

Comment: the instructions were asking to create the UserBook record within an instance method in the User class. So if I understand you correctly, that's not possible?

Comment: No, you have misunderstood. There is nothing preventing you from creating it in an instance method. Its just not possible to add any metadata when you create the join table records implicitly by methods like `books.users << user`.